# How to use JavaScript client-side encryption/decryption in django forms / crispy forms? Is there any python package available which can do this

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, django-widget

Django Form fields needs to be encrypted at server side and needs to be decrypted in client browser while rendering and vice versa for form submission

One approach is using JS cryptographic libraries or to use custom encryption code.

But, Is there any python package available which implements this where we use this as django form widget along with js library at client side.

An example will be a package like the django-autocomplete-light package which provides a widget for autocompletion for the particular field.

How to implement this or Is there any package available which can be used.

Comment: HTTPS is not enough?

Comment: No, it seems using https is not enough for sensitive
fields. requirement is that sensitive form fields should be encrypted or scrambled so that they cant be read even if the form submission is intercepted

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Web Tokens (JWT) has help you in this, in Python Pyjose can help but the quick, how the JS will receive the keybto encrypt the form data with?